# How can i connect webcam stream from javascript to django backend?

Tags: javascript, python, django, opencv

I created a djagno website which use OpenCV to connect with webcam and stream it in browser locally and it worked. But when I uploaded the website on Heroku server, it stopped working. So I used javascript to connect the webcam. But the stream I got from javascript did not seems to be connected with my backend. So how can I connect webcam accessed using javascript and send the stream to Django backend and after processing display it back on frontend?

**Javascript code**

```
var video = document.querySelector("#videoElement");

if (navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia) {
  navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ video: true })
    .then(function (stream) {
      video.srcObject = stream;
    })
    .catch(function (err0r) {
      console.log("Something went wrong!");
    });
```

**OpenCv code**

```
class VideoCamera(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.video = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

def __del__(self):
    self.video.release()

def get_frame(self):
    success, image = self.video.read()
    ret, jpeg = cv2.imencode('.jpg', image)
    return jpeg.tobytes()
```

I know these are a lot of question, so I am expecting a pathway and keywords from where I can learn these concepts. At least give me some direction so I can learn and accomplish this.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to change the way you get the camera feed by using javascript instead of python since your code runs on a server it has no way of interacting with the user's camera or more accurately get user media and sending it to the server to be processed.

I have recently faced this problem and since I only wanted the camera feed to scan the QR code displayed I used a javascript library to scan it and send the data directly to the backend which work far better since OpenCV is a big library

Comment: How did you manage to accomplish it so effectively?
Could you kindly demonstrate how this magical process operates?

Comment: Yes of course :

here is what you will need to add in the  html file :
`       <div class="card-body">
          <video
            id="camera-preview"
            class="w-100"
            autoplay
          ></video>
          <div id="result" class="text-center mt-4"></div>`

Comment: and here is the javascript to get the camera element 

  // Check if getUserMedia is available in the browser
  if (navigator.mediaDevices && navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia) {
    // Access the device camera
    navigator.mediaDevices
      .getUserMedia({ video: true })
      .then(function (stream) {
        // Set the camera stream as the source for the video element
        videoElement.srcObject = stream;

Comment: That's not what I'm looking for.

Comment: I want you to demonstrate the way we can Scan QRCode and send those data to the backend, as you said: `I only wanted the camera feed to scan the QR code displayed I used a javascript library to scan it and send the data directly to the backend which work far better since OpenCV is a big library`

Comment: We just want to know how to use the library you are talking about to implement real-time QR code scanning.

Comment: You should add the code example directly inside the answer instead of in a comment. It will help everyone to see it.